# What does "les ingérences prêtées au rival iranien" mean?

Tags: sens

I am translating this sentence from [an article on Le Monde](http://www.lemonde.fr/proche-orient/article/2017/11/18/liban-l-ex-premier-ministre-saad-hariri-recu-a-l-elysee-par-emmanuel-macron_5216992_3218.html), and I got tripped up by the phrase, "les ingérences prêtées au rival iranien".

> En annonçant sa démission, M. Hariri avait invoqué la « mainmise » du Hezbollah – membre du gouvernement et soutenu par l’Iran – sur la vie politique au Liban, et des craintes pour sa vie, au moment où **Ryad fulminait contre les ingérences prêtées au rival iranien dans la région**.
>
> In announcing his resignation, Mr. Hariri had invoked the "stranglehold" of Hezbollah — a member of the government and supported by Iran — on the political life in Lebanon, and fears for his life, at the moment when Ryadh was fulminating against interference [to/by?] the Iranian rival in the region.

Logically, "interference by the Iranian rival" makes most sense. But that's just a guess. How would you translate the bolded text, and more specifically, "les ingérences prêtées au rival iranien"?

Comment: _Alleged interference by the Iranian rival_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Prêtées* means here that there is no proof about what is claimed.

Quoted from the TLFi [prêter](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%AAter) entry:

> 3. Attribuer à quelqu'un, sans raison fondée et souvent à tort, un caractère, un trait, un acte, une pensée. *Prêter à qqn des aventures, de l'esprit, de la perfidie, de la niaiserie, ses propres sentiments, le dessein, l'intention, la pensée de (faire telle chose)*. *Les gens doubles prêtent toujours aux autres leur duplicité* (Balzac,U. Mirouët, 1841, p.16). *Elle (...) contemplait la salle avec un port de tête et un sourire comme on en prête aux impératrices de légende* (Chardonne,Bonheur Barbezieux, 1938, p.58)

Comment: Oh! Thanks. Would *au rival iranien* be "by the Iranian rival"?

Comment: I'm not accustomed to au or à meaning "by".

Comment: @ktm5124 You could translate as “the interference attributed to the Iranian rival”. Prepositions have very broad meanings.